# Passing List as an argument to another method, but the method accept the parameter as Tuple in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am passing a List as an argument to another method. But the method accepting the parameter as Tuple.

```
class A():
   def method(self):
      lst = [{'CITY': 'Boston', 'STATE': 'MA'},
           {'CITY': 'New York', 'STATE': 'NY'}]
      self.method1(self,*lst)

   def method1(self,*param):
      print(type(param))
      print(param)

b =A()
b.method() # Printing type as Tuple
```

I want to get the List not the Tuple. Any suggestion!

Comment: Remove the `*`. The `*` is for *unpacking* the arguments in to a tuple of positional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `*lst`, you're unpacking the contents of `lst` as arguments to the function `method1`. The function `method1` is actually taking multiple args because you've done `*param` - it takes as many parameters as you pass it.

When you unpack `lst` and pass it to `method1`, it takes it in as a tuple by definition.

Observe:

```
>>> L = ['hi', 'hello']
>>> def A(*args):
...     print(args)
... 
>>> A(*L)
('hi', 'hello')
```

---

To fix your issue, remove both your asterisks and take in a `list` object - don't unpack your list.